# Spring boot MVC does not use the specified custom StringHttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In the class responsible for app config is this code:

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverter<String> createStringHttpMessageConverter() {

    StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter
            (Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    return converter;
}
```

I checked in debugger that it is actually executed and also tried alternative with `StringHttpMessageConverter` as the return type.

However when I debug `WebMvcConfig.extendMessageConverters()` I see that the StringHttpMessageConverter with the default charset is used instead of my converter with UTF-8 charset.

Why does not Spring Boot use the specified `StringHttpMessageConverter` ?

I know the workaround might be to change the converters list according to my needs in `WebMvcConfig.extendMessageConverters()` but I would like to do it the right way

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot [try to register array of `HttpMessageConverter`s](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters):

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.converter.*;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        HttpMessageConverter<?> additional = ...
        HttpMessageConverter<?> another = ...
        return new HttpMessageConverters(additional, another);
    }

}
```

Or if you are not using Spring Boot's auto-configuration, you can use standard Spring [`WebMvcConfigurer` for registering converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-message-converters):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .indentOutput(true)
                .dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                .modulesToInstall(new ParameterNamesModule());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.xml().build()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Using `@EnableWebMvc` is probably not a good idea here as it disables Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC. Your first suggestion, to use a custom `HttpMessageConverters` bean, is what I would recommend.

Comment: I updated my answer. I included second option, because I was working on projects , where we couldn't turn on auto-configuration on day one after migrating to Spring Boot. There were some iterations needed to refactor the legacy configs for auto-configuration. Therefore I think one shouldn't expect usage of auto-configuration with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 steps to support utf-8 StringHttpMessageConverter;
First add StringHttpMessageConverter;Second specify charset in produces,code is below;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/plain")
public class PlainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"})
    public Response<String> test() {

        return new Response<String>("success");
    }
}
```

```
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters fastJsonHttpMessageConverters() {
        FastJsonHttpMessageConverter fastConverter = new FastJsonHttpMessageConverter();
        FastJsonConfig fastJsonConfig = new FastJsonConfig();
        fastJsonConfig.setSerializerFeatures(SerializerFeature.PrettyFormat);
        fastConverter.setFastJsonConfig(fastJsonConfig);
        HttpMessageConverter<?> converter = fastConverter;

        StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter =
                new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        return new HttpMessageConverters(converter, stringHttpMessageConverter);
    }
```